# ffmpeg. Делаю скриншот с rtsp потока. Итоге: изображение серого цвета

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, rtsp

Есть два скрипта:
1)запущен постоянно в фоне, производится постоянная запись rtsp-потока через ffmpeg;
2) запускается по запросу и выводит скриншот.

Во втором скрипте команда:
"ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i 'rtsp://...' -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -y -f mjpeg test.jpg"
Вывод: ...;[hevc @ 0x2264840] Could not find ref with POC 28;...
Открываю изображение, а оно всё серого цвета.

Если первый скрипт работает и в этот момент я открою rstp поток в vlc, то первую секунду серый экран, а после появляется нормальный поток.

Если я отключаю первый скрипт, то второй работает стабильно и на выходе получается необходимое изображение.
Как исправить ситуацию?

Comment: А там точно mjpeg? если да, то пропусти один кадр

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если поток в divx, xvid, h264, или в любом кодеке кроме, наверное, mjpeg 
нужно ждать ключевого кадра. Обычно он раз в пару секунд, но очень зависит от настроек кодека.

В mjpeg первый (только первый если с сетью все хорошо) кадр может быть битым. Пропусти его. Вроде -ss ключ.

По поводу серой секунды - видео сервер поддерживает несколько потоков? Обычные IP камеры умеют только 2 потока.

UPD:
Можно отфильтровать ключевые кадры через фильтр добавив ключи:

```
-vf "select=eq(pict_type\,I)" -vsync vfr
```

`I` - полные ключевые кадры

Comment: IP камера настроена на h265. Пропустить кадр никак не получается. Через -ss пробовал, никак не реагирует, может потому-что это rtsp поток. Есть вариант брать изображение со второго потока, то там скрипт работает, но разрешение небольшое, даже HD не поставить на второй поток.

Comment: Всё! Удалось исправить ситуацию с помощью -ss. Пришлось два кадра пропустить, теперь всё работает. Спасибо!

Comment: Если h265, то пропускай побольше. Надо чтоб ключевой попался. Посмотри, может, есть ключ для этого

Comment: mp4 - не кодек.

Comment: @user1056837, да, Вы правы. имел ввиду H.264 (MPEG-4 part 10, AVC)

Comment: Спасибо! Такой вариант мне больше понравился:" -vf "select=eq(pict_type\,I)" -vsync vfr "