# Серый фон или размазня на скриншоте rtsp потока

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, скриншот

Есть камера xiaomi fang которая после хака научена выдавать RSTP поток через snx rtsp server вот с такими параметрами: snx_rtsp_server -W 1920 -H 1080 -Q 10 -b 4096 -a >$LOG 2>&1 &

VLC его видит и показывает отлично, но при старте первые пару мгновений серое месиво.

Пробую из этого потока через avconv дернуть скриншот:
avconv -rstp_transport tcp -i $url -r 1 -vsync 1 -qscale 1 -f image2 -vframes 1 pict.jpg

Получаю в файле серый экран на котором еле еле проглядываются контуры.

Попробовал по [вот этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/720513/ffmpeg-%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81-rtsp-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%98%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0) совету добавить фильтрацию и поиск ключевых кадров:

avconv -rstp_transport tcp -i $url -r 1 -vf "select=eq(pict_type\,I)" -vsync vfr  -qscale 1 -f image2 -vframes 1 pict.jpg

Картинка стала интересней. Верхняя половина кадра нормальная, а низ размазан
[image: после попытки поиска ключевых кадров]

Игры с ключом -ss X  тоже ничего особо не дали. Меняя количество пропусков мы просто сдвигаем границу размазни вверх или вниз.  Дальше у меня идеи кончились.

Да, со второй камеры, которая "ONVIF что то там" и тоже выдает RTSP поток проблем никаких. Эта же команда выдает четкий скриншот.

Да, в винде тот же первый вариант

ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.1.152/unicast -r 1 -vsync 1 -qscale 1 -f image2 -vframes 1 pict.jpg

работает отлично.

Answer (score 0):

Сам спросил, сам ответил. В общем вопрос решила вот такая комбинация:

avconv -rtsp_transport tcp -i $url -vf "select=eq(pict_type\,I)" -qscale 0 -f image2 vframes 1 -r 1 -y white.jpg